# Excellent web development podcasts

Tags: podcast

Could we get a list of excellent web development podcasts to subscribe to?

I will mark this as a community wiki and add to it as new suggestions come in.

Suggestions so far;

- [SitePoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/category/podcast/)
- [Boagworld](http://boagworld.com/podcast-archive/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Sitepoint Podcast](http://www.sitepoint.com/category/podcast/) is very good.

Answer (score 1):

1. [Syntax.](https://syntax.fm/)
2. [Codepen Radio](https://blog.codepen.io/radio/)
3. [FullStack Radio](http://www.fullstackradio.com/)
4. [ShopTalk](https://shoptalkshow.com/)
5. [Javascript Jabber](https://devchat.tv/js-jabber/)